# Question about some of Sir Francis Galton's table in his book

Tags: history, tables

n Sir Francis Galton's book, "Natural Inheritance" (found [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20200223030308/https://galton.org/books/natural-inheritance/pdf/galton-nat-inh-1up-clean.pdf)) in particular table 12 and 13 on page 209 & pg 210 I noticed that the assumed values for the 'above' and 'below' column were 0.5 units different from the rest of the intervals (e.g. In table 13, the below column is stated as below 63, then The intervals go from 63.5 to 64.5 to 65.5 and so on, until the above column which is 74). Why are the above and below columns assumed to be half of the width of the rest of the intervals, and what is the purpose of doing so?

Comment: Which book? According to http://galton.org/ he wrote over 20 books... Moreover, please provide the direct quote that is unclear for you. Otherwise people who do not have access to the book won't understand your question and won't be able to answer (and I guess most of us do not have Galton's books on our bookshelves...).

Comment: Careful reading of Galton's Note below Table 11 (which is the first of this sequence of three related tables) explains this.

Comment: could you expand? I still don't understand